# What is the equivalent syntax in C#, if any?

Tags: c#, vb6, syntax, equivalent

Does C# have any equivalent for VB6

```
With 
End With
```

Comment: This is a question you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283749/the-vb-net-with-statement-embrace-or-avoid

Comment: The closest you can come is a *really short* variable name. ;) For object initialization, see Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's nothing *quite* equivalent, but C# 3 gained the ability to set properties on construction:

```
var person = new Person { Name = "Jon", Age = 34 };
```

And collections:

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "Jon" },
    new Person { Name = "Holly"}
};
```

It's definitely not a replacement for *all* uses of `With`, but worth knowing for some of them.

Comment: How is anonymous construction related to With blocks? (The asker is clearly referring to the block.)

Comment: @Strilanc: Because With blocks are often used to set multiple properties on a newly-constructed object... and object initializers are the equivalent for *that* bit in C#.

Comment: Oh I see. I confused the anonymous and initialization syntaxes.

Comment: `With` can be used to hold a temporary instance -- `With New cMyClass` -- and then actually call methods (not just init props) before it going out of scope.

Answer (score 14):

C# does not have any equivalent syntax. The closest are object initializers, but they are not the same:

```
var obj = new SomeThing {
    Height = 100,
    Text = "Hello, World",
    ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No.

What comes close are **object and list initializers**.

```
Person p = new Person()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Address = new Address()
    {
        Street = "1234 St.",
        City = "Seattle"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

It is by no means an equivalent, however, if it is the typing you're trying to reduce, you can do.

```
{
  var o = myReallyReallyReallyReallyLongObjectName;
  o.Property1 = 1;
  o.Property2 = 2;
  o.Property3 = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no C# equivalent to Visual Basic's `With` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent in c# -> read more here in the comments http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/11/why-doesn-t-c-have-vb-net-s-with-operator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One near-equivalent would be calling a method that is a member of a class.  You don't have to repeatedly name the owning object inside class members - it's implicit in the fact that the function is a member, called for a given instance.

I doubt a direct equivalent of With/End With is a good idea in C# for this reason.  If you found yourself typing an object's name over and over in a given scope, it's a good indication that the code in question would make a good method on that object's class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct equivalent. You can set properties on construction, as others explained, or you can assign your expression to a variable with a short name. The following should be semantically equivalent:

```
With <expression>
    .something ...
    .somethingElse ...
End With

var w = <expression>;
w.something ...
w.somethingElse ...
```