# How to refer to with object

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

How can i refer to the object i use inside `With` if i want the object itself, not its properties / methods?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")
    Call MySub(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")) ' works OK, but duplicated
    Call MySub(this) ' does not works
    .Range(...).Value2 = 1
    ...
End With
```

+ what is the correct terminology here? i don't even know how to compose a google query for this and get some usefull results (since `with` is a common word)...

---

**UPDATE**: to clarify, i was thinking in terms of a handle like `with ... as handle` from python syntax, not about object-oriented `this` keyword

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  .Sheets("MySheet") is not a method and won't do anything.

Comment: i want to pass an Worksheet argument to my subroutine (i want to call the subroutine on different worksheets as needed) P.S.: if it was a method, why would i want to use it as a `with` argument?

Comment: `.Cells(1).Parent` ...but that's just horrible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about by not using `with` in the first place? It makes your code much more readable, uses no more memory (as the `with` statement has to allocate a temporary variable anyway), and is less confusing.

```
Dim WS as WorkSheet
WS = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("MySheet")
Call vymaz_obrazky(WS)
WS.Range(...).Value2 = 1
```

In the code above, the total cost is one additional line of code (the `DIM` statement), and 9 less keystrokes overall. (The `DIM` statement is 19 keystrokes, changing to `WS` in the three lines is 6 keystrokes, but you've saved the `with` (4) and duplication (30), saving about 9 keystrokes.)

Comment: i guess i was just used to python's `with` (it automatically handles `finally` code to close files, ...), but if there is no reason for it in VBA. (BTW i don't really care about keystrokes or lines, just want to avoid duplicated code)

Comment: I know this was selected as the answer, and in the simplified example code included here, it makes the most sense, but in a more realistic scenario, not using With isn't an option. We use With in VBA because every dot costs cycles and using With reduces dots.

Comment: @phrebh: Nonsense. *dots* do not cost cycles; the cycles required to reconcile the property or method are identical in either case with or without the dots, because they still have to be resolved to the object instance. *with* simply introduces difficulties and lessens keystrokes.

Comment: @Ken White: First of all, every dot seen in the code does cost more, because the With statement creates a local instance of the object so the processor needs to work less to reference it. Benchmarking backs this up. It's not a great difference, but it does exist. Second of all, the With statement does **not** introduce difficulties, it helps produce easier to read, and therefore more maintainable, code.

Comment: @phrebh: Official documentation link for your first point about performance, please. As to your second, that's your opinion, not fact.

Comment: @Ken White: I countered your opinion with my opinion. Then you countered with a disingenuous debating tactic. As is your request for official documentation, which is lacking for most things VBA. [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm) talks about the difference. As does [ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm). And [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283749/the-vb-net-with-statement-embrace-or-avoid) (although not for VBA specifically).

Comment: @phrebh:  *disingenuous debating tactic*? Is that what asking for proof of your claim is? Asking people to back up what they claim are facts is *disingenuous*? Right. Gotcha. You've got nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")

    With ws
        MySub ws
        '~~> Rest of the code
    End With
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")

    MySub ws

    With ws    
        '~~> Rest of the code
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edit**:

> do you have any info about non-existence of "this"? – deathApril 19 mins ago

`this` is basically a keyword from C# which refers to the current instance of the class. The equivalent of `this` in VB is `Me`.

The `Me` keyword provides a way to refer to the specific instance of a class or structure in which the code is **currently executing**. For example in a Userform you can use

```
Me.textBox1.Text = "Blah Blah"
```

In VBA, `Me` can also be used for `thisworkbook`. For example, if you paste this code in the `ThisWorkbook` code Area then it will give you the name of the workbook

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Me.Name
End Sub
```

Similarly when you run the above code from the Sheet Code Area you will get the Sheet Name.

HTH

Comment: +1 helpful, but not exactly what i asked - do you have any info about non-existence of "this"?

Comment: Updating.. gimme few minutes :)

Comment: I have updated the post above... Edit: I see you have already got your answer :)

Comment: uh.. both answers are very helpfull, i guess i like the "without with" option more... and i realised i should ask about `with ... as handle` instead about `this` ;))

Comment: 'With` is useless if you don't have any more code which refers to the sheet but is useful if you have more code which refers to the sheet for example `.Range(...).Value`

Answer (score 2):

Use `.Cells.Parent`.  This only works for worksheets, but there are similar things for some other objects (for a workbook you can use `.Sheets.Parent`)

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")
    Call MySub(.Cells.Parent)
    .Range(...).Value2 = 1
    ...
End With
```