# Is there a Python equivalent to the VB.NET 'With' Statement?

Tags: python, vb.net

I always liked how VB.NET allows you to take a series of statements with long variable names and make them more readable using the 'With' Statement (you can see an example in "[The VB.NET 'With' Statement - embrace or avoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283749/the-vb-net-with-statement-embrace-or-avoid)").  It can really make the code much more readable.

So is there is an equivalent keyword or construct to do the same thing in Python?

Comment: Perhaps you can give a real python example so we can better understand. You can certainly shorten imported names in the actually import statement, for example.

Comment: @MichaelKolber - You're right, it is a duplicate.  Thing is, I did a search before I posted, but that post didn't show up in any of the results.

Comment: @Big_Al_Tx No worries, that's what the community is here for :)

Answer (score 2):

No, but you could do something like this:

```
obj.__dict__.update({
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
})
```

However, working with `__dict__` directly is not advised.

Comment: Could you please explain what's going on here? I don't understand what this is achieving.

Comment: So, why did you advise it then?

Comment: What, exactly, is this *shorter* than?

Comment: Standard Python objects store instance attributes in an `__dict__` attribute, but this by no means universally true and I would not recommend doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Long accessor chains are a code smell. If you find that you're manipulating several attributes of an object gotten via an accessor chain it's time to write a method for it. It's also bad style to grab and manipulate "private parts" of objects without their consent...

Your question might better be phrased as "What is a proper pythonic way to set several attributes of a contained object?" together with an actual real-life example which allows answers to be specific.