# VBA With statement equivalent in other languages

Tags: vba, language-features, language-comparisons

In VBA there is a cool feature called a `With` statement that kind of lets you set the global scope for a block of code. This is useful to change multiple fields of an object and to call methods.

Here is an example:

```
With Forms!main
    .Filter = "tel IS NOT NULL"
    .FilterOn = True
    .Requery  'This is a method!
    If .Recordset.RecordCount> 3 Then
        .BackColor = "Red"
    End If
End With
```

In this example all the statements that begin with `.` refer to fields and methods of `Forms!main`.

I haven't come across a feature like this in any modern language (Javascript, c#, python) and I am wondering if there is a reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a useful Wikipedia article that describes this as [method cascading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading), basically a type of [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). The article includes [dart](/questions/tagged/dart), [pascal](/questions/tagged/pascal) and [smalltalk](/questions/tagged/smalltalk) as other languages with this feature.

It's in Javascript as well, but [note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) that:

> ...using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5
> strict mode

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2}

with (obj) {
  const k = a + b; // no need for a .
  console.log(k)
}
```

And it's also included in C# 9.0 according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64338615/765395) - read all the answers for context.

The other interesting post is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283749/the-vb-net-with-statement-embrace-or-avoid) which has some of the flavour for my answer to the question of 'why' this feature is not more widespread.

The 'sugar' can get 'too sweet' e.g.:

```
k = 99
With foo
    With .bar
        With .baz
            If Not .qux Is Nothing Then
                k = 4
            End If
        End With
        For i = 1 to .NumberOfThings
            k = k + i
        Next i
    End With
    .DoAllTheThings(k, SomeOtherVariable)
End With
```

Suddenly use of `With` is not as useful compared to your more terse and readable example. We can see the feature generates controversy (due to over-use) and this is why it has not really made it into the mainstream.

Comment: The `with` in c# is not exactly the same

Comment: To add to the above, VB.NET's `Imports` (or C#'s `using`) directive have taken away much of why the `With/End With` block is such a useful feature in VBA/VB6.